# Retry subscribe when the result is false

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to keep retrying a call to the server (to see if it returns true).

In my service I created a http call which returns true if it was able to retrieve a value, and returns false when it was unable to retrieve a value (and thus get an error).

```js
public retryServerCheck(): Observable<boolean> {
 return this._httpClient.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'ServerCheck')
  .pipe(
    map(() => true),
    catchError(() => of(false)
    ));
}
```

In my component, I want to retry this until I get back `true`, and here lies my problem.

```js
this._serverService.retryServerCheck()
  .subscribe(
    (isOnline) => {
      if (isOnline) {
        this._helperServer.navigateToComponent('Login', undefined, 0);
        console.log('online');
      } else {
        this.lastRetry = 'A little later...';
        console.log('offline');
      }
    }
  );
```

I tried adding a pipe infront of the subsribe but no luck

```
this._serverService.retryServerCheck()
  .pipe(
    retry(10),
    delay(100)
  ).subscribe(
    (isOnline) => {
      if (isOnline) {
        this._helperServer.navigateToComponent('Login', undefined, 0);
        console.log('online');
      } else {
        this.lastRetry = 'A little later...';
        console.log('offline');
      }
    }
  );
```

I was able to do the retry in my service, but then I'm not able to react to it in my component

```js
 public retryServerCheck(): Observable<boolean | HttpError> {
  return this._httpClient.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'ServerCheck')
    .pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(500))),
      catchError(err => {
        return this._helperService.handelHttpError(err);
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: you have try  `retry(1)` function instead of `retryWhen()`

Answer (score 1):

Both `catchError` and `retryWhen` will suppress errors on the stream. So in the component errors are already handled.

Try either making `retryWhen` responsible for handling the number of retries

```js
// service
public retryServerCheck() {
  return this._httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + 'ServerCheck').pipe(
    retryWhen(error$ => error$.pipe(
      take(10),   // <-- number of retries
      delay(500),
      concat(
        /* either throw your own error */
        throwError('no more retries left')
        /* or to pass original error -- use `NEVER` */
        // NEVER
      )
    ))
  )
}

// component
this._serverService.retryServerCheck()
  .subscribe({
    next: (result) => {
      // succeeded
    },
    error: (error)=> {
      // failed
    }
  });
```

[Run this example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/557f06e6868948c0fe76bf418316d46a)

**OR** adding an [`expand`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/expand/) to the component -- to retry when you have a `false` on the stream.

Read more about [rxjs error handling and specifics of retryWhen](https://medium.com/@kddsky/error-handling-in-rxjs-bac0f96a7def)